# DART unit test results change retroactively

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I wrote some DART unit tests that simulate user's activity and, among other checks,  check a particular visual element (div or iframe) for being visible:

```dart
  documentviewerDiv.hidden = true;

  print('Checking if page panel is hidden');
  test('Checking if page panel is hidden',(){
    expect(documentviewerDiv.hidden, true);
  });
```

If the element stays hidden during the whole test, the results are as expected:

```dart
  PASS
  1 PASS    Expectation: Checking if all UI components are present.
  .....
  3 PASS    Expectation: Checking if page panel is hidden.
   ....
```

However, if the visibility of the element changes at the end of the test, like:

```dart
  documentviewerDiv.hidden = false;
```

the test results get dynamically updated this way (I, actually, can see old results being replaced with the new ones):

```dart
      1 PASS    Expectation: Checking if all UI components are present.
...
      3 FAIL    Expectation: Checking if page panel is hidden. Expected: <true> Actual: <false>

package:unittest/src/expect.dart 75:29     expect
documentviewertest.dart 293:15             repositoryListComplete.<fn>
dart:async                                 _asyncRunCallback
file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-stable/build/src/dart/tools/dom/src/native_DOMImplementation.dart 607  _handleMutation
```

It looks like **all the previous tests** of the element visibility are re-evaluated every time its visibility changes and the output is dynamically updated.

How can I prevent this behavior that modifies the successful test result into unsuccessful retroactively?

Below is the simple test code that shows this behavior:

HTML part:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TestChange</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clickme.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TestChange</h1>

    <div id="myDiv">
     Now you see me
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="clickme.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

DART part:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:unittest/html_config.dart';

void main() {

  useHtmlConfiguration();
  var myDiv = querySelector("#myDiv");

  myDiv.hidden = true;
  test("Test visibility 1", (){
    expect(myDiv.hidden, true, reason:"Is it still visible");
  });


  myDiv.hidden = false;
  test("Test visibility 2", (){
    expect(myDiv.hidden, false, reason:"Is it still invisible");
  });

}
```

When the test runs, the first test is reported as failed. If the myDiv.hidden = true is commented out, the first test succeeds.

Comment: You didn't post the code relevant to this question. What code changes the hidden state?

Comment: I modified the original post.

Comment: The tests seem to interact, that is not normal behavior, maybe there are some async operations going on, but I'm still not able to tell from the code you posted. Can't you just create a full example HTML+Dart and post it here, that can't be that much code.

Comment: I added the code. The original code is quite large, so i tried to present a digest that represents the sequence of the events.

Comment: I guess if you try to create minimalistic example that allows to reproduce the error you will very probably find the problem yourself. This are just code fragments and It's very hard to reason about them. When I copy your code in a main.dart file I get about 20 errors. The problem as you describe it, should be possible to be reproducible with a program of very view lines of code.

Comment: Instead of my cut-down code I posted a very simple example that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: With this code it's quite easy to offer support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, the problem is that you set the visibility `outside` the tests.

```dart
test('sometext', () {
   // some code
});
```

just adds a closure to a list of tests to execute.
The appearance in the main method does not necessarily define the order in which the tests are executed.

Your test will be executed like this

- `myDiv.hidden = true;`
- `test("Test visibility 1", () ...) // register test "Test visibility 1"`
- `myDiv.hidden = false;`
- `test("Test visibility 2", () ...) // register test "Test visibility 2"`
- `(){ expect(myDiv.hidden, true, reason:"Is it still visible"); }`
- `(){ expect(myDiv.hidden, false, reason:"Is it still invisible"); }`

**HINT**

```dart
import 'package:unittest/html_enhanced_config.dart';
useHtmlEnhancedConfiguration();
```

instead of

```dart
useHtmlConfiguration();
```

and you get better looking test results output

Comment: I added some hint that you might find useful.